# Input not supported. Please help!

Tags: grub2, input

I rebooted my computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and now I'm getting an "input not supported" or "mode not supported" (depending on which monitor i hook my computer up to). I understand this is because of some resolution size configuration problem. The monitor is looking for one spec and the computer is kicking out another.

I think I've found which file I need to edit but the problem is I have no GUI because it won't boot! I tried holding shift on boot to get to the GRUB menu but it says "Grub loading.." and then we're back to "input not supported."

I tried to SSH into the computer because I know its IP address but that's not working either for some reason. I can SSH into any other computer on my network but not this one. Could that be related?

Any insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: sometimes the grub menu is triggered by `Esc` or `Arrow Down`. Can you boot into console when pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/default/grub, and uncomment the line (i.e. remove the "# "):

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

... then run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

... and reboot.